# How to count length of missing values for string variables as zero?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, count, string-length

I'm trying to count the length of object variables in a dataframe with Python. A lot of my variables are string with missing values and unfortunately when I try to count the length of missing values it shows as 3 (as it counts "Nan" as a 3 character value).

Here's the code that I'm using:

```py
df_string_mean_with_na = pd.DataFrame(df_string.applymap(len).astype(int).mean().to_dict(), index=[df_string.index.values[0]])
```

where df_string is my starting dataframe and I'm trying to calculate the average length of values for each columns.
I would like to count the length of missing values for object variables as 0, is there a way?

Comment: Is Nan a string in this instance? You could replace it with empty space? df.replace('Nan','')

Comment: Yes, this worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for replace missing values to empty strings before counting `length`:

```
print (Table1)
       A      B    C
0  hello     hi  NaN
1   good     hi   so
2   home  hello   no
```

Test missing values:

```
print (Table1.isna())
       A      B      C
0  False  False   True
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False

df = Table1.fillna('').applymap(len).mean().to_frame().T
print (df)
          A    B         C
0  4.333333  3.0  2.333333
```

**Detail**:

```
print (Table1.fillna('').applymap(len))
   A  B  C
0  5  2  0
1  4  2  2
2  4  5  2
```

If missing values are `strings` use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
print (Table1.isna())
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False

df = Table1.replace('NaN', '').applymap(len).mean().to_frame().T
print (df)
          A    B         C
0  4.333333  3.0  2.333333
```

Comment: Thank you jezreal, this was easier than I expected. Do you know why NaT values are not read as Missing Values for some variables?

Comment: @inegue - I think problem is if use `strftime` with datetimes, then datetimes are converted to strings, what is expcted and unfortnately `NaT` (missing values for datetimes) are not changed to `NaN`, but to strings `'NaT'` (maybe bug, not sure)